# Is it possible to create an array of constructors in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, constructor

I'm trying to get better at writing C++ code and wanted to know if something like this is possible:

I have 256 instructions in an instruction set.
They all have completely different behaviour but with common properties, so I thought about making 256 specific classes that would inherit a common class called Instruction.
Then I'd like to store a constructor (or, even, a pair of constructors) for each class into an array of size 256 and simply create the instructions by doing something like:
Instruction instr = constructorsOPCode;

Is that possible and is that a good way to approach this problem?

Comment: According to [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf), a constructor is a function. And you could *generate* some of your C++ code (with tools like [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/), [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp), [SWIG](https://swig.org/), [ANTLR](http://antlr.org/), [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) etc etc etc). Without some [mre] your question is not clear.

Comment: No and no (although using a 256 array is perfectly reasonable). The first no is because you cannot store constructors anywhere, they aren't regular functions. Of couse you could use regular functions as your 'constructors' instead. The second no is because your approach will suffer from *object slicing*. Once the derived type object has been created you assign to the base type so you lose all the derived type information. Maybe this is part of your design, in which case I'd wonder about having the derived types. Just have the base type and functions which construct versions of the base type.

Comment: You might want to look into a *factory pattern*.

Comment: What's wrong with using a giant switch statement?  I think that until you provide a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve, then anything is on the table and this sounds like XY problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an array of constructors in C++?

No. A constructor is not an object, so it cannot be element of an array.

It is also not possible to point to a constructor with a function pointer, so an array of function pointers won't be useful. Besides, each constructor would have a different signature, and arrays are homogeneous, so you couldn't store the pointers with the correct type in one array anyway.

---

> inherit a common class called Instruction

> and simply create the instructions by doing something like: Instruction instr = constructorsOPCode;

If you create an object of the base class, then it wouldn't be of a derived type, so this cannot work.

It seems like you're trying to invent a polymorphic factory. Something like this could work:

```
std::unique_ptr<Instruction>
makeInstruction(int op)
{
    switch(op) {
        case 0: return std::make_unique<SomeInstruction>();
        case 1: return std::make_unique<AnotherInstruction>();
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't have an array of constructors, that wouldn't be what you wanted anyway, the constructor just initialises the object, it doesn't create it. You can create an array of factory functions though which create the objects:

```
std::vector<std::function<std::unique_ptr<Instruction>()>> constructors = 
{
  []{ return std::make_unique<Instruction1>(); },
  []{ return std::make_unique<Instruction2>(); },
  []{ return std::make_unique<Instruction3>(); },
};

std::unique_ptr<Instruction> instruction = constructors[constructorsOPCode]();
```

Depending on your exact use case `shared_ptr` may be more appropriate than `unique_ptr`.